# SDL2 Rect is not drawing with 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, multidimensional-array, sdl-2

I'm working on a game with SDL2 and C, and I've been trying to come up with a good way to draw a large amount of blocks. I came up with the solution of having a 2D array, called `platforms` that stores the data of the block x and y position, along with the width and height. I'm looping through each of these elements in the `drawLevel()` function, and then putting the data in the `SDL_Rect rect = {}` struct. However, the blocks don't seem to be drawing properly. What is going on here? Perhaps I'm looping through the array incorrectly?

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WIDTH 1200
#define HEIGHT 800
#define BLOCK_SIZE 50

int initialize();
void handle_input();
void drawLevel();

typedef struct {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    bool running;
    int FPS;
    int width;
    int height;
    bool close_requested;
    int input[256];
} Game;

Game game = {
  .running = true,
  .FPS = 60,
  .close_requested = false,
  .input = {},
};


int platforms[3][4] = {
    {400, 400, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {300, 300, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE},
    {200, 200, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    initialize();

    while(game.running && !game.close_requested) { //Game loop

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 181, 247, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(game.renderer);

        handle_input();

        drawLevel();

        SDL_RenderPresent(game.renderer);
        SDL_Delay(1000/game.FPS);

    } //End of game loop

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(game.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(game.window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

int initialize() {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0) { //return 0 on success
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    game.window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE); //creates window
    if (!game.window) {
        printf("error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC; //creates a renderer
    game.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(game.window, -1, render_flags);
    if (!game.renderer) {
        printf("error creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(game.window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void handle_input() {

    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            game.close_requested = true;
            game.running = false;
        }

        //printf("input: %p code: %i\n", game.input, event.key.keysym.scancode);
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            game.input[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
            //printf("True");
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
            game.input[event.key.keysym.scancode] = false;
            //printf("False");
        }
    }
}

void drawLevel() {
    SDL_Rect platform;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            SDL_Rect platform = {platforms[x][0], platforms[0][y], platforms[x][3], platforms[x][4]};
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game.renderer, 156, 104, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(game.renderer, &platform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the inner loop? Why `platforms[0][y]`? What do you think this does?

Comment: @tkausl, thanks for the advice. I figured it out. I don't know how these things make sense to me the first time...